# How to read the all files from specified path using spring 'ResourcePatternResolver'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

I need to get the all files irrespective for its file name using spring ResourcePatternResolver.

I have already tried with following code

```
private static final String BPMN_PATH = "process";
ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resource = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("classpath:" + BPMN_PATH + "**/*.bpmn");
```

But this is only if the file lists are in the classpath(project directory).

In my scenario the files are located in  system directory. For this I have tried with following code

```
private static final String BPMN_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home");
ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resource = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:" + BPMN_PATH + File.separator +"process.bpmn");
```

But this will work only for the specified file (process.bpmn).

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I remember the ant-style wildcard pattern should also work for `file:`.

To load all files in a folder (e.g. `/foo/bar/`)  , you could use :

```java
    resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:/foo/bar/*");
```

Please note that it is only limited to the files included in this folder . It will not include the file inside its sub-folders.

If you want to recursively load all files , even the files in each sub-folders and sub-sub-folder and etc., you could use:

```java
     resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:/foo/bar/**");
```

Comment: Hi, I have use the below code:  `resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file: D:\\Users\\1625047\\ActivitiProcess\\**")` But its not working and I am using the  windows machine

Comment: How about this  ? `resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file: D:/Users/625047/ActivitiProcess/**")` ?

Comment: Sorry Its not working and I am getting the exception `[main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Skipping [D:\Users\1625047\Documents\workspace-sts-tes\springboot-activiti-service-task\ D:\Users\1625047\ActivitiProcess] because it does not exist`

Comment: hey , you input the folder path as `D:\Users\1625047\Documents\workspace-sts-tes\springboot-activiti-service-task\ D:\Users\1625047\ActivitiProcess` which is definitely invalid . Make sure the path that you put into "getResources()" is really a valid path first ...........

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Spring Framework PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html).

1. `/WEB-INF/*-context.xml`
2. `com/mycompany/**/applicationContext.xml`
3. `file:C:/some/path/*-context.xml`
4. `classpath:com/mycompany/**/applicationContext.xml`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html